# Trying the find a more semantic way for writing Spring Entity in Kotlin

Tags: spring, kotlin, spring-data-jpa, nullable, semantics

I have an Spring entity written in Kotlin:

```
@Entity
class Book(
    @Id
    var id: Long? = null,
    var title: String? = null, // cannot actually be null, immutable
    var isInStock: Boolean? = null, // cannot actually be null
    var description: String? = null,
 )
```

All the fields must be nullable, because Spring needs to initialize empty objects.

However, this makes using the entity complicated, because I always have to convert the nullable types to their not nullable equivalents. This is not semantic: I would like to really see, which fields can actually be nullable and which ones cannot (or can only be `null` during the initialization process).

Furthermore, some fields are mutable, but some should never be altered after the entity has been created. It would be nice to use Kotlin's `val` and `var` to make this distinction.

So, I would like to work with the following class:

```
class BetterBook(
    val id: Long,
    val title: String,
    var isInStock: Boolean,
    var description: String? = null,
 )
```

This way it is very clear which fields are mutable and which fields can be `null`.

I pondered upon creating a wrapper around `Book`. Has anybody had a similar thought? Would it be a good solution architecturally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can actually do exactly what you want: define the class with `val` instead of `var` for the immutable properties, give them non-nullable types, and have no default constructor. Spring uses Reflection to get at the member variables underlying the (read-only) properties generated by the Kotlin code when setting the values from the database. And for a default-constructor (which it does need at runtime) there's a [kotlin-jpa plugin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/compiler-plugins.html#jpa-support) that will generate this for you automatically in the compiled code. So basically keep your code exactly as you'd idiomatically write it (as you did for `BetterBook`), and annotate the class with `@Entity`, but make sure to apply that plugin.

Comment: This article will show this plugin in action: https://www.baeldung.com/kotlin-jpa

Comment: I try it out and if it works fine, I would like to suggest this solution to JHipster's Kotlin blueprint (called KHipster).

Comment: Just be aware of one thing with that article you linked: it suggests using data classes for entities.  There are issues with doing this.  See [here](https://kotlinexpertise.com/hibernate-with-kotlin-spring-boot/) for details.

Answer (score 0):

JPA (not Spring) requires no argument constructors and mutable attributes so there really isn't much you can do on that front.

You could convert or wrap your JPA entities into something that looks more like the classes you actually want, but the likely outcome is that it will just bloat your code without making things easier to use.

You might consider a completely different persistence layer which is more flexible when it comes to constructors. Spring Data JDBC might actually fit the bill. It has some support for immutable entities. It is also very different than JPA which might be a good or a bad thing depending on your opinion about JPA.

Read these two article to get an idea of the basic concepts behind it: https://spring.io/blog/2018/09/17/introducing-spring-data-jdbc and https://spring.io/blog/2018/09/24/spring-data-jdbc-references-and-aggregates

Answer (score 0):

I am using JHipster (or KHipster, its Kotlin blueprint). Because all the entities are generated by KHipster, I do not want to change these files, for all my changes would be overridden when I regenerate the entity. After experimenting with different solutions I decided to add an extra wrapper layer.

A wrapper is like a PR manager for the entity. It can be constructed from the entity, then it can be modified in the service layer and once it is time to save it, the wrapper will give you back the updated entity.

This is how a KHipster entity approximately looks like:

```
@Entity
class Agreement(
    @Id
    var id: Long? = null, // should be immuatble
    var description: String? = null, // cannot be null, immutable if `isSigned == true`
    var isSigned: Boolean? = null,
 )
```

Using this entity directly is error prone and not very handy. The wrapper solves all these issues:

```
class AgreementWrapper(agreement: Agreement) {
    val id = agreement.id  // NOTICE that we can now use `val` 
    var description: String = agreement.description!! // NOT NULLABLE 
        set(value) {
            if (isSigned == true) throw Exception("A signed agreement cannot be changed!")
            field = value
        }
    var isSigned = agreement.isSigned!!
        set(value) {
            if (isSigned == true && value == false) throw Exception("You cannot undo it!")
            field = value
        }

    val entity: Agreement // This will give us back the updated entity
        get() {
            return Agreement(id, description, isSigned)
        }
}
```

Furthermore, the wrapper can also by used to create new entities. Adding default values to entities (for instance adding a timestamp) would also require changing the file generated by KHipster, but here there is no problem with it. I just added another constructor to the wrapper, which accepts the necessary parameters and uses defaults otherwise. It can also deal with validation and logging.

Thus wrappers act like a bridge between entities and the service layer.

Comment: Is it a good solution? It is not very fast since I create multiple objects, but it is clear and readable.